# Highlight text from Visual Studio 2008 add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in, code-coverage, highlighting

I'm writing another code coverage tool for .NET with Visual Studio 2008 integration.
Everything goes well except one thing: I can't find a way to highlight some code chunks.

I need it to inform user about covered and not covered blocks.
You can see example of the feature I want on the next screenshot (from native VS code coverage toolset):

[image: Coverage Example]

Can someone provide me a code snippet that highlights text in the code view window?
Links to appropriate MSDN articles related to VS2008 are also appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer, see code below:

```
// retrieving IVsTextManager and highlight id
DTE2 applicationObject = ...; // get it during addin init
Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider serviceProvider = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)applicationObject;
Guid SID = typeof(SVsTextManager).GUID;
Guid IID = typeof(IVsTextManager).GUID;
IntPtr output;
serviceProvider.QueryService(ref SID, ref IID, out output);
IVsTextManager textManager = (IVsTextManager)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(output);
int highlightID;
Guid highlightGuid = ...; // your highlighted text style guid
textManager.GetRegisteredMarkerTypeID(ref highlightGuid, out highlightID);

// highlighting text block in the active view
IVsTextView view;
int result = textManager.GetActiveView(0, null, out view);
IVsTextLines buffer;
view.GetBuffer(out buffer);
buffer.CreateLineMarker(highlightID, startLine, startColumn, endLine, endColumn, null, null);
```

More examples could be found in [MetaScroll Visual Studio Addin](http://code.google.com/p/metalscroll/).

Comment: Worth noting that, for VS2010, the related APIs were significantly reworked (old ones are stil available for back-compat, but new ones are much easier to use).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll take a look at the new APIs after upgrading to VS2010.

Comment: It's very well and helpful. I am also writing plugin for static analyzer for VS 2010 and i have to do same thing with my plugin for highlighting my code with error. Please i am not getting that what should actually i should write in Guid highlightGuid = ...; // your highlighted text style guid
DTE2 applicationObject = ...; // get it during addin init can you write in detail please!!
Again i am new for C# that's why getting problem to understand totally!!
Thank as advance

Comment: VS2010 has different API and example from above will not fit it properly. DTE2 object is passed into plugin initialization routine IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection in VS2008. "highlightGuid" value should be generated by hand out of the code - and written into it in a constant form. It's needed since you also needed to add text colorization keys with the same guid into VS2008 section of Windows registry - to be able to setup colorization colors through VS2008 options dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Another example, but for VS2010: http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/11/04/LearnVSXNowPart38.aspx